# Display content based on roles

Tags: meteor

When an is_admin user looks at the profile of another user I want to be able to control the type of information that is displayed based on the users profile roles. My code below displays nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Path: `adminView.js`

```
Template.adminView.helpers({
    profile: ()=> { 
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id}); 
    },
    userRole: function () {
        var roles = this.roles;

        if (roles === "is_student") {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Path: `adminView.html`

```
{{#with profile}}
    {{#if userRole}}
        display user
    {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Do you have a pub-sub that publishes the user specified by `id`?

Comment: Yes. If I remove `{{#if userRole}}
        display user
    {{/if}}` the correct user is published. Did you want me to update my code with the publish.

Comment: No that's fine. I think I spot the problem - isn't `roles` an array?

Comment: Yep, how does that change things?

Comment: @MichelFloyd sorry, trying to decode your comment. I've been searching for ways to check the array in the helper however I can't get it to work. Would you mind helping me out a little more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `roles` is an array you have to check for existence of the value in the array, not equality:

```
userRole: function () {
    var roles = this.roles;
    return (roles.indexOf("is_student") > -1 );
}
```

Comment: As always, your solution worked like a charm! Thanks